# top CSS property just wont work while left is working fine

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a website using the grid system of bootstrap but I am encountering a strange error with top and left CSS properties. I have a header which is divided into two parts, THE COL-MD-8 part where the text lies and the other part COL-MD-4 where the image lies.
The text inside col-md-8 should be horizontally and vertically aligned in the center and to achieve that, I was trying to give relative position to parent and absolute position to child which holds the text but the text container strangely is moving left on left: CSS property but is not responding to top: property.

my HTML part is below

```
<header class="header">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                    <div class="header__left">
                        <div class="header__content">
                            <h2 class="heading-secondary mb-4">
                                Web designer & developer.
                            </h2>
                            <p class="paragraph mb-4">
                                Something about me that explains what I do and what I dont
                            </p>
                            <button class="button button-primary">Let's have a Chat</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="header__right">
                        PHOTO
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

and now my SCSS (css)

```
.header {
    background: $color-brown-dark;
    padding: 2rem;
    height: 98vh;
    color: $color-gray;

    &__left {
        position: relative;
    }
}

.header__content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 60%;
}
```

In above CSS, left is working fine and top is not working at all.
Please help me. Thank you everyone in advance

Comment: If you parent has small or 0px height, then 50% seems line not working...?

Comment: @Justinas, i tried height: inherit on &__left {} but it still didnt work?

Comment: Try `top: 48vh`?

Comment: ok so now it worked with vh but why was top not working with % and left was working fine?

Comment: What is actual height of parent of `.header__content`? `%` is taken from direct parent height